# Kirchhoff's Voltage Law does not hold for a free source RC circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, voltage, capacitance

Say I have a simple free source RC as depicted in the image below. The capacitor initially has a charge of Q on its positive plate and at time t=0 the switch is close. I use the mesh current as shown in the diagram and apply KVL to that loop.

[image: Text]
But then the result I get does not have the minus sign infront of the t in the exponent indicating that the capicator is charging up not discharging. Is this because KVL does not apply here? I have seen some other unconvincing answers to this but none of them apply KVL and I ideally want to understand it in terms of KVL.

Any help on this would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K.V.L. does apply here. Your mistake lies in incorrectly substituting the current in the resistor for the time-rate-of-change of charge in the positive-plate of the capacitor. The $I$ in the expression is actually $I(t)$ and it relates to the charge on the positive plate of the capacitor. Notice that as the charge flows around the circuit in the form of current, the charge on the positive plate *decreases*, so $I(t) = -dQ/dt$. Replace that in  your equation and get the right answer.

Comment: Ah okay I think I get it. So basically $\frac{dQ}{dt}$ refers to the rate of change of charge on the capacitor. Since the capacitor is discharging it must be a negative quantity.  Since I have assumed my current direction to be positive going clockwise, when I perform KVL going in the clockwise direction I have to say that $I(t)=-\frac{dQ}{dt}$ at the resistor  and if I dont put that minus in front then I am basically putting my current into the DE as a negative value (since $ \frac{dQ}{dt} <0$) despite the fact that i have assumed clockwise as positive. Right?

Comment: @SalahTheGoat Precisely. "Charge on the capacitor" almost invariably refers to that on the positive plate.